# Using range on AnyObject value

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm working on a bluetooth project at the moment and after getting the value of the *kCBAdvDataManufacturerData*:

```
var data = advertisementData.value(forKey: "kCBAdvDataManufacturerData")
```

The values are hex values:

```
<00133377 08d704de ff03c200 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00337701 416e746f 6e206465 20426f64 65000000 00000000 00000000>
```

what I know so far is that the value of `kCBAdvDataManufacturerData`key is an `AnyObject`

From the above value I need this:

00133377 08d704de ff03c200 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 **00337701 416e746f 6e206465 20426f64 65000000 00000000 00000000**

How can I get this value without converting it to a String? In other word is there a way to use something like `Range` on a AnyObject value without converting it to a String?

Comment: The value is `(NS)Data` not `AnyObject` and you can extract parts by range.

Comment: Thank you for your respond I'll try using range on the Data and I let you know